# Angular 9: how to re-render component

Tags: angular, components, angular-changedetection

I have one parent and one child component. If the child component updates its value internally I am unable to update value back from Parent.

See the example in this Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tynepp. When the child component loses focus I fire an event and the parent resets value of the child component. But I think that because the parent's "this.value" didn't change that the update doesn't trigger detection changes in the child.

How can I solve this dilemma?

Comment: Please give a [mre].

Comment: Please check Stackblitz link I provided

Comment: From the link above, emphasis in the original: *"Make sure all information necessary to reproduce the problem is included **in the question itself**"*

Comment: Do you want only to change the value of the child component from the parent component? Or have the same value on both components?

Comment: Just value of the child component @bjdose

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you said, change detection is not triggered because the bound value has not changed. You can force an update of the data binding with the following steps:

1. Set a temporary value
2. Call `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()`
3. Reset the value

```js
constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

resetValue() {
  this.value = "____TempValue____";
  this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  this.value = "";
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-szoyyw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for a demo.

Comment: bit hackish but did the trick. thank you @ConnorsFan. Im surprised that there is no cleaner solution to this

Comment: You Are a Master Bro. After whole day, finally it was only solution which worked for me, to dynamically disable option of ng-select, from triggered method in component. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I have created a Directive for my project and it's really easy to use

```html
<ng-container *rerender='changingInput'>
  this content will be re-rendered everytime `changingInput` changes
</ng-container>
```

Check out my [Gist](https://gist.github.com/anhkind/3a3c4b2833d87468deff829497e271ec) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Another simpler approach to get this can be to use the template variables as you can see in the example below:

`parent.component.html`

```html
<app-my-child 
  #child
  (lostFocus)="child.value = ''"></app-my-child>
```

Solution available [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cfpsza).

Comment: looks like this solution only works for the 1st time when focus is lost. after that its not reset. @bjdose

Answer (score 0):

Here is another simple trick.

The browser/Angular does not detect well changes of primitives.
If you rely on that, you can change your primitive to an object.
Angular detects object changes much better.

For example:

If you have in ts:

```
refreshOnThisValue: number = 0;
```

and in HTTP view:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="refreshOnThisValue">

   ... render something

   show value: {{ refreshOnThisValue }}

</ng-container>
```

Change it in ts:

```
refreshOnThisValue: Number = new Number(0);
```

and somewhere in the ts code, where the value needs change and to trigger the refresh enter:

```
                  // newValue is the new number

this.refreshOnThisValue = new Number(newValue);
```

and in HTTP view:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="refreshOnThisValue">

   ... render something

   show value: {{ refreshOnThisValue.valueOf() }}

</ng-container>
```